# How to print "Hello" in C without using a semicolon?

Tags: c

I know there are several ways to do this. Such as:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()  { 
      if (printf("Hello")) 

      return 0;
}
```

But, how do I do this by removing the semicolon after return 0; as well? 
Considering the fact that I can't use void as the return type of main()

Even this article below ignores this fact and skips return 0; statement though the return type of main() is int: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-geeks-for-geeks-without-using-a-semicolon/amp/

Comment: You can drop the return statement altogether

Comment: How can I do that? int is the return type of main() ! The code will not complie in most of the modern compilers if I do that!

Comment: it absolutely does compile: ‪https://godbolt.org/z/Fqp5O6 ‬

Comment: Don't put off until the function body what you can do in the parameter "declaration": `int main(int C, char *V[puts("hello world")]) { }`. :P

Comment: Is this a practical problem, or a programming puzzle?

Comment: This is just a puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as `main` is declared with a type compatible with `int`, it will return 0 at the last `}` if there is no explicit return statement:

[**C Standard, § 5.1.2.2.3**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1), *Program Termination*:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument; reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.

So this code will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if(printf("Hello"))
    {

    }
}
```

The real question is why you would want to write a program without semicolons. [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/) submissions are usually a bit more involved than just that.

Comment: why do I sometime get `shell returned <some garbage>` when I run code without return statement?

Comment: @Gox which version of the C standard is used by the compiler you are using to compile your code? This sounds like a good topic for a separate question if it's one that mandates an implicit `return 0` for `int main`, and that's what you have

Comment: I have `gcc 7.3.1`

Comment: @GovindParmer I cannot replicate the problem now so if I ask a question it will be deleted anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Since the C99 standard, if there's no explicit `return` statement from the `main` function then an *implicit* `return 0;` will be added by the compiler.

Then you can have empty blocks of code using only `{}`.

Putting it together it could be something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (printf("Hello\n"))
    {
    }
}
```